# Flutter: Bottom Overflow by 35 Pixels

Tags: flutter, dart

So, i'm building a project to college on a notes app. On my Sign-in form a message appears when the mobile keyboard appears that says: Bottom Overflow by 35 Pixels.

Here is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Cadastro'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 24),
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: "Primeiro nome",
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  return value!.isEmpty ? "Informe seu primeiro nome!" : null;
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 24),
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: "Sobrenome",
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  return value!.isEmpty ? "Informe seu sobrenome!" : null;
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: "E-mail",
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return "Informe seu e-mail!";
                  } else if (!value.contains('@')) {
                    return "Insira um e-mail válido.";
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 24),
              child: TextFormField(
                obscureText: true,
                // controller: _email,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: "Senha",
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  return value!.isEmpty ? "Informe sua senha!" : null;
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          formKey.currentState?.reset();
                        },
                        child: const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                          child: Text("Limpar"),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          formKey.currentState!.validate()
                              ? Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
                                  (Route<dynamic> route) => false)
                              : formKey.currentState!.validate();
                        },
                        child: const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                          child: Text("Cadastrar"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I've already tried to use **SingleChildScrollView** on the form and on the Expanded's column. Either way the problem persists or a exception is thrown. Is there another way to solve this?

I've tried to use **resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false** as well, got basically the same results

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the `Column` with a `SigleChildScrollView` and set the `mainAxisSize` of the `Column` to `MainAxisSize.min`.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Cadastro'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
           child: Column(
             mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
             children: [
               ...
             ],
           ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```